# SQL JOIN+COUNT QUERY

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm trying to display a table showing a list of courses.  I would like to include a column which shows the number of people who have completed the course and if possible, also the number who have yet to complete it.

My table structure is like so:

```
Courses
courseid | title | etc

Studying
courseid | studentid | some other fields | has_completed
```

Ideally the output should be something like this for example:

```
Course Title | some other fields | Students completed | Students not completed
Something      etc                 5                    3
```

I'm having difficulty getting the two separate fields counted.  Can anyone recommend a good way to do this?

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
SELECT c.CourseID, c.Title, SUM(s.Has_Completed) Completed, SUM(1-s.Has_Completed) NotCompleted
FROM Courses c
LEFT JOIN Studying s ON c.CourseID = s.CourseID
GROUP BY c.CourseID, c.Title
```

Answer (score 1):

If has_completed has value 1 for true and 0 for false, you can solve it very simple:

```
SELECT c.title, SUM(s.has_completed) as completed, COUNT(studentid) - SUM(s.has_completed) as notCompleted
FROM Courses c, Studying s
where c.courseid = s.courseid
GROUP BY c.courseid, c.title
```

Comment: Courses with no students will be left out in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [SQL count command](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_func_count.asp)

```
SELECT COUNT(has_completed) FROM Studying WHERE has_completed='1'
```